# Deploy a server with VS Express

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webserver

I am trying to deploy a server that I can hit from a different computer in my office.  I only need one, two computers to hit it max.  I am using Visual Studios Express 2012 RC for Web and have the whole website made, but I can't figure out how to actually deploy it.  When I click play to debug it (after I have told it to build the web site) it brings it up on my computer that I built the server on but I can't hit it from another computer.  The address it gives me on the browser is localhost:XXXXX.  I know local host means that computers IP and I have tried that repeatedly.  I am stumped.  Please help.  I thank you for any help you give in advance.  Also if you need more information please feel free to ask.

Comment: Can you please add more information to "can't it from from another computer?" Does it time out? Is an error displayed?

Comment: How are you hosting the site IIS Express? I've read it's possible to accept connections other than from localhost. You can always use the full IIS server on the computer. Make sure you are also using the IP and not local host.

Comment: I am using IIS Express.  When I try to access it from another computer it tells me that I put in a bad host name even though I put in the host computer's IP and the port it told me.  XXX.XXX.X.XXX:XXXXX

Comment: From http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/  - IIS Express is a lightweight, self-contained version of IIS optimized for developers. IIS Express makes it easy to use the most current version of IIS to develop and test websites. It has all the core capabilities of IIS 7 and above as well as additional features designed to ease website development including: It doesn't run as a service or require administrator user rights to perform most tasks. IIS Express works well with ASP.NET and PHP applications. Multiple users of IIS Express can work independently on the same computer.

Comment: There is nothing in this documentation that says it can or should be used in production, only for developing and testing.  There is also nothing that says you can use it remotely.  You need full fledged IIS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run it from Visual Studio Express, you have to deploy the web application to an IIS server. You can't access the site if VS is not running, because it creates a local, specialized development server when you start the application, whether with debugging or not.  You need to configure IIS on your web server.  What is the OS?  Once you go through a tutorial to set it up, you will copy your code to an application folder that will be created for you.  The details vary by IIS version.

> Internet Information Services (IIS) – formerly called Internet
>   Information Server – is a web server application and set of feature
>   extension modules created by Microsoft for use with Microsoft Windows.
>   IIS 7.5 supports HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, FTPS, SMTP and NNTP. It is an
>   integral part of the Windows Server family of products, as well as
>   certain editions of Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7. IIS is
>   not turned on by default when Windows is installed. The IIS Manager is
>   accessed through the Microsoft Management Console or Administrative
>   Tools in the Control Panel.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services

http://www.iis.net/

Comment: I believe its IIS 7.  I tried to update it and that's what I downloaded.  How would I configure it to the server?  Is that not what VS runs by default?

Comment: To configure it, we need to know more about your setup.  What is the server OS, what type of network, what type of security etc.

Comment: Well how would I upload it to a server then?  I've been using what it gives me in VS and my boss swears it should work.  The computer is hooked up to a D-Link router and there is an external firewall......somewhere here and I don't know what kind it is.

Comment: Also, it doesn't need to be a super nice server.  It's for a one-time-use thing.  we are using it for a demo here so really I just need the easiest most simple way possible to upload this thing.

Comment: What OS is your "server" running.  A server can be any desktop, if you are doing this with lean resources.

Comment: If this is a one time use thing, why did you not design it as a winforms application or wpf and just copy the exe to the multiple computers?  Trying to shoehorn a solution into a web app when you don't have the infrastructure (the web server set up and configured) seems like a bad way to go.